# Best way of login from app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have  developed some Apps. and i use some **Login feature**. when need to use **login** i call **php Api login**. i send username and password to server which my php developer handle. and give return success.and i had saved isLogin true in app preference.and next my app check is login true then open next page not need to enter again username and password.but i know this is not a fine way to login. in this i found if app is installed in **other mobile** and **change password** then in **first mobile**, app login already true and enter in next page. so can anyone tell me **what is proper way to login**.

Comment: send devicetoken with every login and check if devicetoken is different then ask user to login again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need return a token to device after login, this token will be saved in shared preference and in next app session you must use it to check if login is valid or not (make an api call with token and return yes or not).

If user change password you change the user token on your db, in this way, the first user will get an error on token and you can show the login view easy